# c# Merged cells as header address epplus

Tags: c#, epplus

How do I set HeaderAddress to two cells of a clustered bar chart in EPPlus? I have the below data from my database output, where first column is as you can see merged cells.

[image]

I am looking for the following layout of the data [image]

*Please take note that the images are from a replica of the data, but generated inside Excel.*

What I've tried so far is basically

```
ExcelChartSerie s = chart.Series.Add(axis.Address, xAxis.Address);
s.HeaderAddress = new ExcelAddress(startRow + r, GetColumnNumberByName(startColumn), startRow + 1, GetColumnNumberByName(startColumn) + 1);
```

where I more or less select the current row and two columns. This gives me **"Address must be a row, column or single cell"**, but in order to get this to work, I must select multiple cells, no?

Answer (score 2):

Epplus does not have the ability to set it.  it is not so difficult but it requires XML manipulation.  Kind of ugly but it gets the job done.  Not knowing your code I made up a quick unit test that demos.  It has to match to the right chart type so if it is not `BarClustered` let me know:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void Chart_Meged_Header_Test()
{
    //Throw in some data
    var datatable = new DataTable("tblData");
    datatable.Columns.AddRange(new[]
    {
        new DataColumn("Col1", typeof (string)),
        new DataColumn("Col2", typeof (int))
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var row = datatable.NewRow();
        row[0] = $"item {(i%2 == 0 ? "A" : "B")}";
        row[1] = i * 10;
        datatable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    //Create a test file    
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\Chart_Meged_Header_Test.xlsx");
    if (fileInfo.Exists)
        fileInfo.Delete();

    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
    {
        var workbook = pck.Workbook;
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        worksheet.Cells["B1"].LoadFromDataTable(datatable, true);
        worksheet.Column(4).Style.Numberformat.Format = "m/d/yyyy";

        var chart = worksheet.Drawings.AddChart("chart test", eChartType.BarClustered);
        var serie = chart.Series.Add(worksheet.Cells["C2:C11"], worksheet.Cells["B2:B11"]);
        chart.SetPosition(0, 0, 3, 0);
        chart.SetSize(120);

        //Add merged headers
        worksheet.Cells["A2"].Value = "Group 1";
        worksheet.Cells["A2:A6"].Merge = true;

        worksheet.Cells["A7"].Value = "Group 2";
        worksheet.Cells["A7:A11"].Merge = true;

        //Get reference to the worksheet xml for proper namespace
        var chartXml = chart.ChartXml;
        var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(chartXml.NameTable);

        var nsuri = chartXml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI;
        nsm.AddNamespace("c", nsuri);

        //Get the Series ref and its cat
        var serNode = chartXml.SelectSingleNode("c:chartSpace/c:chart/c:plotArea/c:barChart/c:ser", nsm);
        var catNode = serNode.SelectSingleNode("c:cat", nsm);

        //Get Y axis reference to replace with multi level node
        var numRefNode = catNode.SelectSingleNode("c:numRef", nsm);
        var multiLvlStrRefNode = chartXml.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "c:multiLvlStrRef", nsuri);

        //Set the proper cell reference and replace the node
        var fNode = chartXml.CreateElement("c:f", nsuri);
        fNode.InnerXml = numRefNode.SelectSingleNode("c:f", nsm).InnerXml;
        fNode.InnerXml = fNode.InnerXml.Replace("$B$2", "$A$2");
        multiLvlStrRefNode.AppendChild(fNode);
        catNode.ReplaceChild(multiLvlStrRefNode, numRefNode);

        //Set the multi level flag
        var noMultiLvlLblNode = chartXml.CreateElement("c:noMultiLvlLbl", nsuri);
        var att = chartXml.CreateAttribute("val");
        att.Value = "0";
        noMultiLvlLblNode.Attributes.Append(att);

        var catAxNode = chartXml.SelectSingleNode("c:chartSpace/c:chart/c:plotArea/c:catAx", nsm);
        catAxNode.AppendChild(noMultiLvlLblNode);

        pck.Save();
    }
}
```

Gives this as the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will test this out and see. I will mark as completed once I understand all and get it to work once.

Comment: Do you know any tool on how to debug broken excel? I tried this, and your code is working perfect with new charts, but when I try to apply this to existing charts, it breaks and excel removes the broken chart, but I cannot find the problem. I tried the SDK tools, but it validates, so I do not know where to start

Comment: @Pochen I would not be surprised with that.  I bet that since it was actually saved by Excel (and not EPPlus) excel has added some or all of the new XML properties we are creating above.  So, anywhere there is a `CreateElement` or `CreateAttribute` you will have to check to see if it is already there.  If it is it would have to be updated rather then creating a brand new entry for it.  If you cant figure it out post your file somewhere and we can take a look at it.

Comment: This is the result now; no crash, and ALMOST gruped. http://s7.postimg.org/4iak573u3/img.png

I found out noMultiLvlLbl was duplicated so this is the new code used to prevent it from duplicating.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Wq6Ju

Comment: @Pochen  Humm..nothing really jumps out at me.  Maybe make sure the caches are cleaned out.  Open the xlsx with 7zip and inspect the chart1.xml files before and after.  Post the files somewhere if you get stuck.

Comment: I've opened the file in the SDK tool, but I'm lost. I cannot find where the error might be. You are more than welcome to take a look at http://jmp.sh/Jg6mdbo when/if you find the time

Comment: @Pochen  The problem is the `multiLvlStrCache`.  It contains the two levels `c:lvl` but the second one should not list 25 of them - it should only list how many should be at that level  - Accident, Near Accident, Non Conformity.  Not quite should how that is being set if you are adding the `multLvlStr` node from scratch.  Post the file before you ran that code on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105877/discussion-between-pochen-and-ernie).